# Using Reflection in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, asp.net-core, .net-core

For cross-platform development, I'm trying to make a .NET Core shared library.  I used the `Class Library (package)` project template in VS 2015.  My library needs to use a couple reflection mechanisms I am familiar with from the full .net 4 framework, but I don't now how to access these in a .NET Core library.  Specifically:

- The `Delegate` type has a `Method` property that returns a `MethodInfo` object.
- The `Type` class has a `BaseType` property, `FilterName` property, `InvokeMember` method and `FindMembers` method I can't reach in .NET Core.

I added NuGet packages that allegedly have the reflection pieces I need:

```
"frameworks": {
  "net451": {
    "dependencies": {
      "System.Reflection": "4.1.0-beta-23516",
      "System.Reflection.Extensions": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
      "System.Reflection.Primitives": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
    }
  },
  "dotnet5.4": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
      "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
      "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
      "System.Reflection": "4.1.0-beta-23516",
      "System.Reflection.Extensions": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
      "System.Reflection.Primitives": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
      "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
      "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
    }
  }
},
"dependencies": {
  "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions": "4.1.0-beta-23516"
}
```

I've also added `using System.Reflection`, but I still am getting errors that indicate that these properties and types are undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

In case it is relevant, on this same machine the command `dnvm list` shows:

```
Active Version           Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias  
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------------- -----  
    1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x64          win                    
    1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x86          win                    
    1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x64          win                    
*    1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x86          win             default
```

The above is exactly what I want...or at least what I think I want. ;)

Comment: .net Core is still under development and is not complete. It's possible System.Reflection is not ported into .net core yet.

Comment: At least for the `BaseType` you can use `type.GetTypeInfo().BaseType`, that's where it has been moved in since WinRT/UWP (which is roughly on what .NET Core is based on, the `System.Runtime`). Much of the standard calls have been removed behind `GetTypeInfo()` and similar methods

Comment: When are you getting errors? What are those errors?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Short Answer

> What am I doing wrong?

You are trying to access members that are available in .NET 4.5.1 but not in 5.4.

```
4.x                        Workaround in 5.x/Core

Delegate.Method.           Delegate.GetMethodInfo()
Type.BaseType.             Type.GetTypeInfo()
Type.FilterName            -
Type.InvokeMember          -
Type.FindMembers           -
```

## Snip directly from Visual Studio.

Visual Studio tells us this if we hover our mouse over the error.

[image: ype.BaseType is not available...]

## .NET Portability Report

It is also worth looking at the [.NET Portability Analyzer](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/support-dotnet-core-instructions.md#how-to-use-portability-analyzer). It is an extension that we can install from the [Visual Studio Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1177943e-cfb7-4822-a8a6-e56c7905292b?SRC=VSIDE).

Running it tells us, for instance, that `Type.BaseType` is not available and recommends a workaround.

[image: .NET Portability Analyzer output]

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want your original code full of `#if ... #else ... #endif` statements, you could use a helper library like https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReflectionBridge/ which provides some extensions which define a bridge for the differences between Type and TypeInfo.
(Source code at https://github.com/StefH/ReflectionBridge)

Answer (score 4):

I'm using .net Core 1.0. Try following snippet of project.json and see if works for you.  I have also noticed that you are using beta API so if possible stay way from beta.

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "compilationOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
    },

    "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.0.0-rc2-23811",
        "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions": "4.0.0"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnxcore50": { }
    }
}
```

Comment: `NETStandard.Library` is not available from NuGet; I am unable to use it.  Where did you get it from?  Evidently, [it is not in a published location](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/535).  Also, what exactly is `NETStandard.Library`?  I didn't find any articles or documentation written about it.

Comment: I ran `dnvm restore` a couple weeks before creating this project.  I've updated my question to show `dnvm list` results on my machine.  Are you saying this is *still* not good enough?

Comment: Please see your project.json file. It's referencing beta assemblies. e.g. "System.Reflection": "4.1.0-beta-23516". Please update version to non-beta and restore again.