# Getting the public properties of a class in .NET core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I notice that .NET core doesn't allow `myObj.GetType().GetProperties()` as no `GetProperties` method exists. Is there another way to obtain the properties of a class through reflection?

Comment: `myObj.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetProperties()`

Comment: Have you tried with this pkg https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.TypeExtensions/ ?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36118978/using-reflection-in-net-core

Comment: Nkosi No GetTypeInfo method appears to exist in .NET core

Comment: It does, it's just an extra package. That's the philosophy in .NET Core - that's why the project is named "Core". Reflection isn't part of the core, since it means horrible dependencies, which make .NET Native a lot less useful.

Comment: Actually, it would appear I was missing a Using declaration for System.Reflection! Not using resharper at the moment! Thanks

Comment: @user3791372 post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems that `myObj.GetType().GetProperties()` IS valid. I just had to bring in System.Reflection by `using System.Reflection`.

Answer (score 11):

Just to sum up to anyone else, just adding `using System.Reflection` to the top of the page is not enough. You will have to add the `System.Reflection.TypeExtensions` NuGet package as described in the question comments.

> PM> Install-Package System.Reflection.TypeExtensions -Version 4.3.0

Comment: 1/ This is a comment to a comment written as an answer, 2/ No you don't. 3./ This garnered an upvote surprisingly quickly.

Comment: Yes you do. I had the same issue in a .NET Standard 1.6 project and only the combination above solved it for me. In .NET Core unfortunately namespaces are now spread over multiple assemblies.

Comment: 1/ Yeah you do 2/Seems like if you're answering your own question (and not a complete answer) you're on shaky ground about getting picky with upvotes... I upvoted both of you... Together it's a complete answer

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou the question refers to ".Net Core" not .Net Standard