# Could not use Delegate's Method Property in C#?

Tags: c#

When i try to use Delegate's Method Property in C# i get this error.

> 'myDelegate' does not contain a definition for 'Method' and no
>   extension method 'Method' accepting a first argument of type
>   'myDelegate' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

I really don't know the reason why i get this. My program is fairly simple and is based on delegates. Below it's code is given:

```
public delegate void myDelegate(int x);
public class Program
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        X x = new X();
        myDelegate d = x.InstanceProgress;
        Console.WriteLine(d.Method);
    }
}

class X
{
   public void InstanceProgress(int percent) => Console.WriteLine(percent);
}
```

I get error on this line:

```
Console.WriteLine(d.Method);
```

See this image below, although i get the proper output but i get the error. 
I have marked the error with green arrow on the image.

[image]

Comment: Just so you know, its "delegate" not "deligate" (though a deligate sounds somewhat delicious...)

Comment: What framework are you targeting?

Comment: Solution DNX SDK version : 1.0.0-beta5

Comment: What method from InstanceProgress you want to execute? Obviously, InstanceProgress does not contain Method in its definition. Is this some example from some book or something similar?

Comment: "InstanceProgress" is itself a method.I should get this output - Void InstanceProgress(Int32)

Comment: @freshbm Well, there is the member _Method_ but it is a Method description member. You cannot invoke it.

Comment: What exactly is the desired outcome here? Are you perhaps looking for `GetMethodInfo()` in the `System.Reflection` namespace? Are you wanting to invoke the delegate, are you wanting to find information on the method?

Comment: Copy/pasted your code, it works as expected...

Comment: @ColinM yes u r right i am trying to get information of the method. It's not about invoking the method through deligate.

Comment: Now I see the issue and have reproduced this, does `GetMethodInfo()` suffice?

Comment: @ColinM i have shown on the image this error. Why i get this error, although I get the method information on the console window ?

Comment: @yogihosting, try to clean the solution and restart visual studio. It doesn't look like it's an actual error.

Comment: I cleaned solution and restarted the VS just now. Still no difference.

Comment: @Cory are you using a NET Core application? I am reproducing this just fine on my instance of Visual Studio.

Comment: @yogihosting https://stackoverflow.com/a/36145196/5062791

Comment: No, I'm using VS2015 with .Net 4.5.1

Comment: I'm reproducing on VS2017 with NET Core Console App

Comment: I am using VS2015, it seems it is related to net framework.

Comment: So it seems like the appropriate thing to do here is to raise this as a bug with Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

Looking at OP's screenshot. That looks like a Visual Studio error. And since it lets you build the it's not a true error. I don't get that error in VS2015.

I'd clean the solution and restart visual studio. That should clear it.

**Old:**

You'll want to do something like this:

```
X x = new X();
myDeligate d = x.InstanceProgress;
d.Invoke(5);

// or as Rahul pointed out you can simply use
d(5);
```

Invoke() is what actually calls the method. Until then the delegate is just a pointer to the method that you want to call.

Comment: why not just `d(5)`?

Comment: this is not about invoking a method. .Method is a inbuilt property that provides the name and parameters of the method that will be invoke.

Comment: @yogihosting Then what would you expect to happen in your original code?

Comment: Then your delegate would need to point to a class instead of a method

Comment: Well, though this is a correct answer but certainly OP isn't looking for the same. you might want to see OP's comment in question

Comment: @Rahul my question is not about invoking a method through deligate, its finding the method information